# Animation when UITableviewcell are being drawn

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a fully working `UITableView`, with delete, sort, insert and etc.

How can I set animation like Fading, Middle or Down to the `UITableViewCell` when the cells are being added to the UITableView, not when using `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert`, but when items are being added from an array

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to insert a cell (with `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`) for each object you add?

Probably something like this:

```
- (void)addContentFromArray:(NSArray *)array {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[array count]];
    for (id object in array) {
        NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.dataSource count] inSection:0];
        [self.dataSource addObject:object];
    }
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Im currently using `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}` and `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ return cell;}`